# Artifacts on video transcoded from GIF by Elastic Transcoder

Tags: amazon-web-services, video, ffmpeg, amazon-elastic-transcoder

I'm trying to transcode GIF to MP4 with H.264 inside using AWS Elastic Transcoder. I noticed strange color artifacts on transcoded video: color stripes on the right.

Original GIF:

[image: Original GIF]

Transcoded video screenshot:

[image: Transcoded video]

I've tried to change settings, even changed output format to WEBM+VP8: same result. My local ffmpeg has no such issue, so I think there is something on ET side.

My MP4 settings, if what:

[image: Transcoding settings]

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Does the artifact in the resulting video move at all, or is it static?

Comment: @Umopepisdn, not static. Here is transcoded video: https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/funcorn-dev/tests/test3.mp4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The width of the image is 381, an odd number that might be getting mishandled during re-scaling.

Try cropping off one pixel on the right to make the image 380x150.